# If the array has an even number of elements which value becomes the "perfect" pivot for Quicksort?

Tags: sorting

Let's say we have an array which consists -5,1,-9,-3. I assume that the perfect pivot is the one which partitions the array into two equal subarrays, but that's only possible with arrays which have odd number of element. As I understand the perfect pivot in this case would be either -3 or 1 as they are not the elements with lowest or highest value?

Comment: Hoare partition scheme partition step can end up with pivot element anywhere, so it doesn't exclude any elements from recursive calls, and works with even number of elements. Ignoring run time issues, odd sizes could be handled with Lomuto scheme, where pivot is excluded, even sizes with Hoare, where pivot is left somewhere in either sub-partition. I don't know how a "perfect" pivot could be chosen without a big impact on run time.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, multiple pivots will be equally good.  Further, if one uses a three-way subdivision where all items equal to the pivot get grouped in the middle, the optimal choice of pivot would depend upon more than just the number of elements above and below the pivot, but also their value distribution.  For example, given [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7] the median value is 3, but pivoting around 3 would require one pivoting operation on the left and two on the right, while pivoting around 4 would result in only one additional operation being needed on each side.

Comment: But won't the subarray [1,2,2,2] be pivoted more than once, as the Quicksort doesn't  really compare the values that are in the subarray?

Comment: @Martynas: An enhancement to Quicksort does a three-way partition involving elements less than the pivot, equal to the pivot, and greater than the pivot.  Pivoting [1,2,2,2,3] would split it into [1], [2,2,2], and [3].  The first and third groups are only one element in length, while the second group only contains one value (equal to the pivot).  Thus, none of the groups need any further action.

Comment: But if the three-way partition is emitted then it would take equal number of pivoting in each array right?